# Regarding identification of burnt IC

Tags: transistors, mosfet, identification, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

Hey there I bought a 3 axis gimbal for my drone, but unfortunately it ran into a problem. The roll motor stopped working and it heats when the gimbal is powered, so I tried to look at the issue and found a burnt IC. On googling the number it did not come up. So I got my multimeter hooked up and check for similar ic beside it. After all my research I have come to know that there are 3 similar IC on the board which individual power the 3 phases of BLDC gimbal motor (5 ohm resistance per phase). The IC has 6 pins, according to the multimeter

Pin 1 - input from microcontroller

Pin 2 - VCC (5v)

Pin 3 - feedback (guess) it is connected to pin2 via 10k resistor

Pin 4 - Ouput to motor

Pin 5 - GND

pin 6 - Ouput to motor

I have few conclusion after the following findings.

1. Some kind of transistor
2. Single Phase Half Bridge Inverter

I am not sure if these are true or not but I need to find what this IC is as soon as possible.[image][image]

Comment: the board itself does not look very healthy ... what would be the point of replacing the burnt component? ... the real cause of the failure probably still exists

Comment: Sir it's almost new gimbal which cost 150USD you can check the prices it's TAROT TL3T05. Also I have paid import duties for it not gonna let it go this way

Comment: wow, expensive ... it makes sense to try a repair

Comment: There is a chance that if you contact the manufacturer they would send you a replacement part.

Comment: I have mailed them the issue, and requested them for a schematic if possible, but I am keeping my hopes low about getting one.

Answer (score 1):

There are many dual MOSFET P/N chips with a matching pinout like for example DMG6602SVTQ or FDC6432SH. If you know the voltages and current requirements of the motor, you may probably just choose one of them and give it a run.

Comment: Omg !!thank you so much, this has almost solved the issue of identification, but I don't know the motor ratings the only thing I know is it has 5 ohm resistance between it's phases. Also the good MOSFET read out 5v on drain ports and S2 port/ VCC port

Comment: @UnmeshSawant: I would prefer DMG6602SVTQ for a test. I had a look at digikey and mouser and I'm sorry to say, that nearly all good matching parts are sold out currently. The sum of the plateau voltages should be > 5V for low cross conduction and Ron < 0.1 ohm to work properly here with 1 A phase current. You can try others with lower plateau like SIL2308 or SQ3585, but they may get very hot. We don't know enough of the driver circuit to be sure. And be aware, that the FETs are probably only the victims of another problem (weak cable? metal particle?)

Comment: Alright, I will find something similar to test out with, one thing I would like to share is I desoldered the MOSFET and thoroughly checked the board for any other kind of shorts and found a capacitor which is showing continuity, initially I had check the same cap but thought it might be because of the MOSFET but it's still there. I feel there is more things which have gone bad also the only chip left to diagnose is the S033 PHVC (STM microcontroller) if that's bad then in that situation the whole board needs a replacement. I have contacted the seller for the same, let's hope for the best.